# ternary operator/default value in neo4j cypher

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I need to implement something of a ternary operator that can help me return some default values from cypher query itself.

Scenario is -

> if an employee's city is Delhi, return 5 else return 10

Something like a ternary operator.

```
start employee = node(5)
return employee.city == 'DELHI' ? 5 : 10 as val;
```

I tried things like

```
start employee = node(5)
return coalesce (employee.city == 'DELHI', 5)
```

but no luck.

Is there a way to implement such a scenario in neo4j be it Cypher or Traversal.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately it is not supported out of the box but here is a hack to do it, using filter, head and collection literals.

The idea is to have a two element list and a filter expression that becomes true for the first element for your "true-branch" and alternatively true for the second element in the list whic represents the value of your false-branch.

see this console example: http://console.neo4j.org/r/6tig7g

```
start n=node(5) return head(filter( a in [5,10] : n.city = 'DELHI' OR a = 10))
```

so generally:

```
head(filter( a in [true-result,false-result] : CONDITION OR a = false-result))
```

Comment: Is this not implemented as a standard feature yet?

Answer (score 3):

I know this is a really old question, but since Google landed me here and I have an answer (Cypher in Neo4J 3.5+):

```
MATCH (employee:Employee)
RETURN 
CASE employee.city WHEN "DELHI" THEN 5 ELSE 10 END AS val
```